# logstash can`t parse type completion to numbers

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I created an index which has type completion in elasticsearch, however, when I tried to use `logstash` to automate fetching data from the database, I faced the following error:

> failed to parse [x]: expected text or object, but got VALUE_NUMBER

only on `x` which its type is completion.

The only solution that I'm thinking of is to change type of `x` to number rather than string when fetching it from a database.

I tried to search on every support site for elastic search and I did not get any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way is to create a new column with the same number but now AS STRING.
I hope someone will benefit for it in the future.